# Filling pre-exisitng Excel form using vbscript

Tags: sql, excel, vbscript, adodb, jscript

Running an old Classic ASP site, and up to now I made my own "Excel" file with HTML, that gets sent to our accounting dept. They've revised the Excel file they want us to use, so I can't use my old method. So I'm connecting to the excel file directly (ADODB), and I can update the necessary cells easily enough. The problem is that they've added some fields at the bottom of the "form", including some with SUM() formulas, and left 34 rows for entries in the middle. We often need more than that.

I've tried "insert into" sql, and tried "rs.AddNew", and those both put the data into the row below the range I'm targeting; fair enough. However a NEW ROW is not added to the file - the data goes into the row below. It isn't like inserting a row manually in Excel, and pushing any lower rows further down. Does anyone know how I can do this through ADO/SQL? Or is it simply impossible?

As a last resort, I'll just have to create an extra document to hold the overflow past 34 entries.

Thanks!

I finally found something that [reflects my problem](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2007/10/17/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-insert-new-rows-above-the-last-row-in-an-office-excel-spreadsheet/), but it is VBA (I think):

```
Const xlDown = -4121

Set objExcel = CreateObject(“Excel.Application”)

objExcel.Visible = True


Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(“C:\Scripts\Test.xls”)

Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)


Set objRange = objExcel.Range(“A1”)

objRange.End(xlDown).Activate


intRow = objExcel.ActiveCell.Row

intColumn = objExcel.ActiveCell.Column

Set objRange = objWorksheet.Cells(intRow, intColumn).EntireRow


For i = 1 to 10

    objRange.Insert(xlShiftDown)

Next


For i = 1 to 10

    objExcel.Cells(intRow, 1).Value = i

    intRow = intRow + 1

Next


strFormula = “=SUM(A1:A” & intRow – 1 & “)”

objExcel.Cells(intRow, 1).Formula = strFormula
```

Any way to make this work on a server in VBscript??? :-)

Comment: ADODB won't expand it's rows. You can add rows but you need to requery from a **new** connection (ie not just requery from the existing) to be able to access them. See https://www.google.com.au/search?q=HOWTO:+Use+ADO+and+ADOX+with+Excel+Data+from+Visual+Basic+or+VBA

Comment: I won't need to requery in the Excel file. I'm creating a one-off file that gets emailed to our accounting department, and they use SAP to suck out the data. My only problem is if, for example, we have 45 transactions to add into the Excel file, "they" only put in 34 rows for this data. Now, if I was editing the file manually, I could insert extra rows as needed. But my script does this for 5 different departments, and I'm trying to automate it. ;-)

Comment: You can insert rows at the end but need to requery on a new connection to access them.

Comment: Sorry, Noodles, I'm not explaining it right, because I don't need to access them again. I need to insert them, but where I'm meant to insert them is in the middle of rows with other info. The accounting department accommodates 34 rows in their "form"; if I have more rows of data than 34, I need to insert (as in create) them ABOVE some cells that have formulas. So far, I've not found a way to do that with ADODB. And there may not be a way. I hope that clears up that I don't need to query the file again.

Comment: I understand. I'm saying what's possible. I'm explaining the limitations of ADODB and Excel. Use COM if you want more than limited control over the file. ADODB is for accessing databases (tables) not spreadsheets (adhoc organisation), so it treats spreadsheets as databases so they should be tables ONLY.

Comment: OK, I'll dig into what COM can do, thanks. And yes, big limitations! Thanks for your time!

Comment: You can record the steps in excel's macro recorder. This will give you a program mostly written for you. **Alt + T, M, R** repeat to stop. This will give you VBA in a style VBS can't understand. Convert named parameters to positional (ie `func(Param1 =: "A", Param2 =: "B")` to `Func("A", "B")`.

Comment: FYI @ChrisMetropolis what you've posted above as your example is VBScript, not VBA.  It's not exactly how I'd put it together though.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't do this using ADO (you'd just end up overwriting your formulae) you will need to directly access the workbook.  The code you found is close but what's below should fit your needs.  Let me know if you need any further explanation?

```
Option Explicit

Const xlDown = -4121
Const xlUp = -4162

Dim objExcel, objWorkbook, objRange, iLastRow, myRecordCount, numInserts, intLoop

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Scripts\Test.xls")
Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1) ' refers to first worksheet

iLastRow = objWorksheet.Cells(objWorksheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set objRange = objWorksheet.Cells(iLastRow, 1).EntireRow

' myRecordCount will need to hold the number of records you have
If myRecordCount > 34 Then 
    numInserts = myRecordCount - 34 ' get the number of rows to be inserted
Else
    numInserts = 0
End If

For intLoop = 1 to numInserts
    ' for as many rows as we need, insert above the formula
    objRange.Insert(xlShiftDown)
Next

' insert your data into the worksheet here

objWorkbook.Save
objWorkbook.Close
objExcel.Quit

' send the file out however you're sending it
```

Comment: Thanks, Dave. I'll try that out - I'm wondering about `CreateObject("Excel.Application")`, since the code is on a web server run by my school board, and I wouldn't be surprised if Excel is not installed.